# Replacing string elements of a pandas DataFrame with integers

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
   x_axis  y_axis  data
0  Cheese   farms     4
1   wales  Cheese     3
```

That can be generated with the following code:

```
import pandas
cols=['x_axis','y_axis','data']
row1=['Cheese','farms',4]
row2=['wales','Cheese',3]
data=pandas.DataFrame([row1,row2],columns=cols)
print data
```

In reality the data I have is much bigger and the `x` and `y axis` are labels to a heat map. Because these labels are often quite large I want to enumerate them and replace them with an index (across both `x` and `y axes` i.e. so if `cheese` is `1` in `x` it is also `1` in `y axis`). I also need to be able to write a legend that maps the new indexes to their original values.

The desired output might look something like this:

```
  x_axis y_axis  data
0      1      2     4
1      3      1     3
```

Then the legend would be:

```
cheese=1
farms=2
wales=3
```

Can anybody give me some suggestions on how to do this programmatically?

Comment: You mapping may not be fully clear. What happens if you have duplicates, such as  an additional line row3=['Bread','wales',3]?

Comment: Hi tfv, so 'bread' would always be 4 (for example) and wales always 5 - regardless of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [categorical variables](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html).

Because you want to convert values in multiple columns, you need to `stack()` into a series and then call `astype`:

```
>>> s = df.loc[:, ['x_axis', 'y_axis']].stack().astype('category')
>>> s
0  x_axis    Cheese
   y_axis     farms
1  x_axis     wales
   y_axis    Cheese
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Cheese, farms, wales]
```

`s` is now a Series with categorical types: each unique string is mapped to an integer.

If you use the `.cat` accessor, you can get the integer code of each categorical variable. Using `unstack()` will give you back a DataFrame:

```
>>> s.cat.codes.unstack()
   x_axis  y_axis
0       0       1
1       2       0
```

This means that you can assign these integer columns back to the original columns with the following:

```
>>> df.loc[:, ['x_axis', 'y_axis']] = s.cat.codes.unstack()
>>> df
   x_axis  y_axis  data
0       0       1     4
1       2       0     3
```

The mapping of strings to integers is given by `s.cat.categories` in the form of an Index (so 'Cheese' = 0, 'farms' = 1, 'wales' = 2):

```
>>> s.cat.categories
Index(['Cheese', 'farms', 'wales'], dtype='object')
```